# How does depth of field work in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, depth-of-field

I am currently writing a paper on different renderers, I have created a scene and rendered it with different engines (Arnold, Renderman, Cycles and Luxcore) and it appears that different renderers have very different results when it comes to depth of filed and bokeh. They differ in the amount of blur and the look of it, even when all factors are the same (same aperture size, focus distance etc). Does anyone have an idea of why this is? How exactly is depth of field calculated in blender? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello :). This will depend on the engine. There are differences between Cycles (raytracing), Eevee and Workbench.

Comment: Cycles is the one I'm working with :)

Comment: have you also considered sensor size? A larger sensor results in more blur on real camera's

Comment: Yes, the sensor size is the same in all of them, as are the rest of the parameters in the scene and camera settings :)